# String not in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use Regex to find matches in a string. There are other ways to find the pattern I am looking for, but I am interested in the Regex solution.

Concider these strings

```
"ABC123"
"ABC245"
"ABC435"
"ABC Oh say can You see"
```

I want to match the find "ABC" followed by ANYTHING BUT "123". What is the correct regex expression?

Comment: As for your regex question, negative lookahead `/ABC(?!123)/` http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Does your string always starts with "ABC" ?

Comment: @Habib: No. It could be placed anywhere

Comment: Do you want just the ABC in the match, or whatever follows it too? If you want what follows it too, how do you define that boundary?

Comment: Do you **have** to use regular expressions? Although they work, it would be better to use code you are more likely to understand. I find REGEX hard to read personally although it is useful if you get a correct string.

Comment: `if (target.BeginsWith("ABC") && !target.BeginsWith("ABC123"))` is going to be more readable than any regex, in my opinion...

Comment: @LukeHennerly: I don't have to, but I want to. I aggree that it is insanely difficult to learn the syntax, but it is such a powerful tool for advanced string comparrison, so I want to learn.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I aggree, but if there are other tests, other if's will follow. Further, I want to learn regex. Also, a regular expression can be stored in a config file, and thus changed without code refactoring, as your understanding of the input string changes.

Comment: If you're learning regexp, I *highly* recommend that you download Regex Builder, which is a tool designed to help you learn and debug regexp: http://regexbuilder.codeplex.com/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: If you are in it for the glory, you should move your comment to an answer, so I can give you points for the correct answer :-)

Comment: On work turn atm, sorry for the late answer. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [negative lookahead](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/ABC(?!123)/
```

You can check if there are matches in a string `str` with:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "ABC(?!123)")
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] strings = {
            "ABC123",
            "ABC245", 
            "ABC435",
            "ABC Oh say can You see"
        };
        string pattern = "ABC(?!123)";
        foreach (string str in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "\"{0}\" {1} match.", 
                str, Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern) ? "does" : "does not"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/wQ7pMD)

Alas, my Regex above will match `ABC` as long as it is not followed by `123`. If you need to match at least a character after `ABC` that is not `123` (that is, do not match `ABC` on its own/end of the string), you can use `ABC(?!123).`, the dot ensures that you match at least one character after `ABC`: [demo](http://ideone.com/BAeSsw).

I believe the first Regex is what you're looking for though (as long as "nothing" can be considered "anything" `:P`).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following test code. This should do what you require

```
string s1 = "ABC123";
string s2 = "we ABC123 weew";
string s3 = "ABC435";
string s4 = "Can ABC Oh say can You see";
List<string> list = new List<string>() { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
Regex regex = new Regex(@".*(?<=.*ABC(?!.*123.*)).*");
Match m = null;
foreach (string s in list)
{
    m = regex.Match(s);
    if (m != null)
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
}
```

The output is:

```
ABC435
Can ABC Oh say can You see
```

This uses both a ['Negative Lookahead' and a 'Positive Lookbehind'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's **way** too complicated.  All you need is `/ABC(?!123)/`, as Fabricio said in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498707/string-not-in-regular-expression#comment21942974_15498707).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regex, should you find this easier to use. Only a suggestion.

```
  List<string> strs = new List<string>() { "ABC123",
                                           "ABC245",
                                           "ABC435",
                                           "NOTABC",
                                           "ABC Oh say can You see" 
                                          };
  for (int i = 0; i < strs.Count; i++)
  {
    //Set the current string variable
    string str = strs[i];
    //Get the index of "ABC"
    int index = str.IndexOf("ABC");
    //Do you want to remove if ABC doesn't exist?
    if (index == -1)
      continue;
    //Set the index to be the next character from ABC
    index += 3;
    //If the index is within the length with 3 extra characters (123)
    if (index <= str.Length && (index + 3) <= str.Length)
      if (str.Substring(index, 3) == "123")
        strs.RemoveAt(i);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am only interested in Regex solutions. Edited the question to emphasize this.